# What happens to failed queued tasks in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a process that when receives a request through REST made by another process it schedules jobs. Each time it's called, it schedules a new job.

What happens if for some reason a job can't be executed? The next time it has to be executed, but if it never happens? Could tasks be queued and then make me have a problem with memory?

Answer (score 0):

If the task is not accepted you should get a [TaskRejectedException](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskRejectedException.html) that you can handle. If the task is accepted it should eventually run. If you schedule tasks far off in the future and keep adding more tasks or if the system is overloaded and can't process the tasks fast enough of course you can run out of memory eventually. However, a task is not likely to consume that much memory, so in that case you will probably have other more urgent problems first!